# Как установить правильные координаты Inline SVG Circle?

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Я могу сделать встроенный круг SVG [как здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp):

```html
 <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg>
```

Однако, я  пытаюсь понять свойства `cx` и `cy` и `height` и `width`.

Я хочу получить круг 15x15 пикселей, вокруг которого нет свободного места, но я не могу понять, как сделать это правильно.

- Этот вариант показывает только правый нижний угол

```html
<svg height="15" width="15"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="9" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" /></svg>
```

- Этот SVG разрезает круг на квадрат

```html
<svg height="15" width="15"><circle cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="9" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" /></svg>
```

Как правильно достичь того, чего я хочу?
Вы можете попробовать [сами здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_circle):

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to set correct Inline SVG Circle coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64537187/7394871) от участника  [@SimonS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5084424/simons).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64537187/7394871

Comment: Кому то этот топик покажется слишком простым, но для людей начинающих изучать SVG, на мой взгляд он будет полезен. Так как на начальном этапе возникает очень много вопросов по позиционированию.

Answer (score 1):

*Мне хотелось бы показать общую технику, как с позиционировать элемент SVG, чтобы не было лишнего пустого пространства вокруг элемента.*

1. Для наглядности сделаем границы холста SVG видимыми
   Для этого в шапке файла SVG напишем стиль CSS

`style="border:1px solid"`

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" style="border:1px solid">
  <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

2. Следующим шагом является определение параметров `width, height, x, y`,прямоугольника, ограничивающего окружность,  с помощью метода JS [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid">
  <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg> 
<script>
let bb = circ.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

По результатам видно, что ширина прямоугольника составляет 80px, отступы от начала холста SVG 10px, справа отступ тоже 10px
**итого:** `10 + 80 + 10 = 100px`

3. Если вы хотите, чтобы не было пустого пространства вокруг svg элемента необходимо убрать эти отступы, уменьшив ширину холста и добавить немного пространства, чтобы умещалась обводка окружности шириной 3px

```html
<svg height="84" width="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84" style="border:1px solid">
  <circle id="circ" cx="42" cy="42" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg> 
<script>
let bb = circ.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

Рамку вокруг холста можно удалить, так как она использовалась для визуальной отладки позиционирования.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539162/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>